# How to implement multi-processing in a web-server (python)?

Tags: python, server, webserver, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have been following a tutorial to write a python webserver: [ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part3/](http://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part3/).

There is a simple code for python web-server that is supposed to handle requests using multiprocessing

```
import os
import socket
import time

SERVER_ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT) = '', 8888
REQUEST_QUEUE_SIZE = 15

file = open("test.html", "r")
http_response = file.read()

def handle_request(client_connection):
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)

    print(
        'Child PID: {pid}. Parent PID {ppid}'.format(
            pid=os.getpid(),
            ppid=os.getppid(),
        )
    )
    #print(request.decode())
    '''http_response = b"""\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Hello, World!
"""'''
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    time.sleep(15)


def serve_forever():
    listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    listen_socket.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)
    listen_socket.listen(REQUEST_QUEUE_SIZE)
    print('Serving HTTP on port {port} ...'.format(port=PORT))
    print('Parent PID (PPID): {pid}\n'.format(pid=os.getpid()))

    while True:
        client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
        #print "parent is now accepting new clients"
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:  # child
            #print "aaaaaaaa", pid, "aaaaaaa"
            listen_socket.close()  # close child copy
            handle_request(client_connection)
            client_connection.close()
            print ("child {pid} exits".format(pid=os.getpid()))
            os._exit(0)  # child exits here

        else:  # parent
            print "parent process continues"
            client_connection.close()  # close parent copy and loop over

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve_forever()
```

This is supposed to return a simple webpage to the client and wait for 15 seconds to close the connection.
During the 15 seconds, other clients should still be able to connect and receive the webpage, but it seems like the other clients have to wait for the previous child process to end in order to do that.

How can I implement true multi-processing where the at least 4-5 clients can get the webpage without waiting for the previous child process to end?

(of course I can remove the sleep() function, but that would not truly solve the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Use a new thread to accept connection from clients

Comment: It appears that the question wants to avoid the use of threads and instead use multiprocessing